# What's the best approach for building this grid layout?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have this grid layout that I've built using fixed sizes with pixels, but I'm not sure how to make it responsive? I've read about using fr's, but I don't understand how that works without setting a specific width for the container? would that be good p ractice?

Secondly, this ties into another more general issue that I'm repeatedly running into and don't see answered very well in any guide: how am I supposed to set the overall width and height of my page - what's best practice? I've tried 100vw and 100vh and 100% and auto, but they all seem to come with some issues. I'd like a layout that fits the screen in height and width.

HTML + CSS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
<div class="container">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="nav"></div>
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="main"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>


.content {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
}
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 200px 200px 600px 100px;
    grid-template-columns: 300px 700px;
    gap: 15px;
}

.header {
    background-color: blue;
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3;
}

.nav {
    background-color: red;

}

.sidebar {
    background-color: green;
    grid-area: 2 / 1 / 4 / 2;

}

.main {
    background-color: brown;

}

.footer {
    background-color: chocolate;
    grid-area: 4 / 1 / 4 / 3;

}
```

Comment: To be responsive you just have to use percentages rather than fixed pixel values. if you have a 1000px container your columns can just be 30% & 70%. If you want to use `fr` then sub in `3fr` and `7fr`. Same effect.

Comment: Sweet, and would it be good practice to make a container for the entire content of the page and give it a fixed size of say 1000px?

Answer (score 1):

To make your grid layout responsive and address your concerns about setting the overall width and height of your page, you can use various CSS units and properties to create a flexible and responsive design. Here are some suggestions:

**1. Use fr Units for Grid Layout:**
Instead of setting fixed pixel sizes for your grid rows and columns, you can use fr units (fractional units) to make your grid layout responsive. By doing so, the grid will automatically adapt to the available space in a container.

Here's how you can modify your grid layout:

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 3fr 0.5fr; /* Use fr units for rows */
    grid-template-columns: 30% 70%; /* Use percentages for columns */
    gap: 15px;
}
```

This allows the grid rows to take up fractions of the available space, making it more responsive.

**2.Viewport Units for Page Width and Height:**
To set the overall width and height of your page to fit the screen, you can use viewport units like vw (viewport width) and vh (viewport height). These units are relative to the viewport, and they can help you create a layout that adjusts to the screen size

```
.content {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100vh; /* Set content height to 100% of viewport height */
}
```

By setting the .content height to 100vh, it will fill the entire height of the viewport.

**3. Media Queries for Mobile Responsiveness:**
To make your design more adaptive to different screen sizes, consider using media queries. You can define specific CSS rules for different screen widths, which helps ensure your layout looks good on both large screens and mobile devices.

Here's an example of a media query for mobile responsiveness:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .container {
        grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr 2fr 0.5fr;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
}
```

This media query adjusts the grid layout for screens with a maximum width of 768 pixels.

By combining these techniques, you can create a responsive grid layout that adjusts to various screen sizes and maintains a flexible design. Remember to test your layout on different devices and adjust your CSS rules as needed to achieve the desired responsiveness.

**Also for responsive layout, Do not forget to add the following meta tag to your HTML, if you haven't already.**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Thank you so much! My question about the fr units would be: What are they taking up fractions of? From what I see, there's no specified width for the container? Would it then be fractions of the parent divs width or the body width?

Comment: @ofg Yes, 'fr' means a fraction, you can explore more about the 'fr' unit here on this https://css-tricks.com/introduction-fr-css-unit/ link.

Comment: @ofg Right now, the container is taking width from its parent class, you can add width if you want.